# Why does ansible ad hoc debug module not print variable?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to debug my ansible setup by running

```
ansible -m debug -a 'var=ansible_distribution' all
```

but I'm getting

```
my_ansible_host0 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_distribution": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

It seems I can use `{{ansible_distribution}}` in my jinja templates, though.  Why is this?  (Is this, for example, something to do with the distinction between facts and variables that I haven't been able to figure out yet?)  And how can I change my command to get it to print out the value of `ansible_distribution`?  (Do I need to do something with `lookup(...)`?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ansible_distribution` fact is created implicitly by the `setup` module when you run a play.  You may have noticed this when running a playbook:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************
```

This is Ansible running the `setup` module to get information about a remote host. When you're running ad-hoc commands, there is no "gathering facts" step, so these variables aren't available.

If you want to see the value of `ansible_distribution` and other variables, you can manually run the `setup` module:

```
ansible -m setup all
```

You can limit collected facts using parameters to the [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) module. For example:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_dist*'

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_distribution": "Fedora",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/redhat-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "RedHat",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "31",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "31"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```