# Variable is undefined when running Ansible 'debug' ad-hoc

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-ad-hoc

Could you explain why following behaviour happens. When I try to print remote Ansible IP with following playbook everything works as expected:

```yaml
---
- hosts: centos1
  tasks:
    - name: Print ip address
      debug:
        msg: "ip: {{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]}}"
```

when I try ad-hoc command it doesn't work:

```bash
ansible -i hosts centos1 -m debug -a 'msg={{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]}}'
```

Here is the ad-hoc error:

> centos1 | FAILED! => {
> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses' is undefined.
> 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses' is undefined" }

I don't find any difference in both approaches that is why I was expecting both to work and print the remote IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I don't find any difference in both approaches that is why I was expecting both to work and print the remote IP address.*

This is because no facts were gathered. Whereby via `ansible-playbook` and depending on the configuration [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) become gathered automatically, via `ansible` only and ad-hoc command not.

To do so you would need to execute the `setup` module instead. See [Introduction to ad hoc commands - Gathering facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_guide/intro_adhoc.html#gathering-facts).

**Further Q&A**

- [How Ansible sets variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042933/how-ansible-sets-variables-required-pkgs/71043335#71043335)
- [Why does Ansible ad-hoc `debug` module not print variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59145677/6771046)

Please take note of the variable names according

- [Conflict of variable name `packages` with `ansible_facts.packages`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70759895/6771046)

---

> *Could you please give some example on **How to output "Your IP address is "`{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0] }}`"?** using ad-hoc approach with `setup` module?*

**Example**

```json
ansible test.example.com -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'
test.example.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "192.0.2.1"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

or

```json
ansible test.example.com -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_default_ipv4'
test.example.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_default_ipv4": {
            "address": "192.0.2.1",
            "alias": "eth0",
            "broadcast": "192.0.2.255",
            "gateway": "192.0.2.0",
            "interface": "eth0",
            "macaddress": "00:00:5e:12:34:56",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "network": "192.0.2.0",
            "type": "ether"
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

It is also recommend to have a look into the full output without the filter argument to get familiar with the result set and data structure.

**Documentation**

- [`setup` module - Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#examples)

Answer (score 1):

You can run ad-hoc commands that use gathered facts if you set up an [ansible Cache plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) first. Notice the first `debug` fails, but after running `setup` once, now `debug` starts working.

```bash
$ export ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN=jsonfile
$ export ANSIBLE_CACHE_PLUGIN_CONNECTION=/tmp/ansible-cache
$ mkdir /tmp/ansible-cache

$ ansible myMachine -m debug -a 'msg={{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]}}'
myMachine | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses' is undefined. 'ansible_all_ipv4_addresses' is undefined"
}

$ ansible myMachine -m setup
myMachine | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
...
}

$ ansible myMachine -m debug -a 'msg={{ansible_all_ipv4_addresses[0]}}'
myMachine | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "10.50.1.1"
}
```