# Ansible save register to file

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have the following playbook:

```yaml
- name: Get-IP
  hosts: webservers

  tasks:

    - debug: var=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
      register: foo

    - debug:
        var: foo

    - local_action: lineinfile line= {{ foo }} path=/root/file2.txt
```

I added `debug` to make sure variable `foo` carrying the IP address, and its working correctly, but when I try to save it to file on local desk, files remains empty. If I delete the file I get an error about the file does not exist.

Whats wrong with my playbook? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write the lines in a loop. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        dest: /tmp/ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.webservers
        line: "{{ item }} {{ hostvars[item].ansible_all_ipv4_addresses|join(',') }}"
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook  pb.yml

PLAY [webservers] ****************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***********************************************************************
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_13]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 10.1.0.61
ok: [test_13] => 
  ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
  - 10.1.0.63

TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
changed: [test_11 -> localhost] => (item=test_11)
changed: [test_11 -> localhost] => (item=test_13)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.webservers
test_11 10.1.0.61
test_13 10.1.0.63
```

Answer (score 0):

According your description and example I understand your use case that you like to gather [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) about Remote Nodes and [Cache facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) on the Control Node.

If [fact cache plugin is enabled](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#enabling-fact-cache-plugins)

```ini
~/test$ grep fact_ ansible.cfg
fact_caching            = yaml # or json
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible/facts_cache
fact_caching_timeout    = 129600
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: test
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "network"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts network
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

will result into local files like

```yaml
~/test$ grep -A1 _ipv4 /tmp/ansible/facts_cache/test.example.com
ansible_all_ipv4_addresses:
- 192.0.2.1
--
ansible_default_ipv4:
  address: 192.0.2.1
--
...
```

By following this approach there is no need for re-implementing already existing functionality, less and easier to maintain code, less error prone, and so on.

Furthermore,

> *Fact caching can improve performance. If you manage thousands of hosts, you can configure fact caching to run nightly, then manage configuration on a smaller set of servers periodically throughout the day. With cached facts, you have access to variables and information about all hosts even when you are only managing a small number of servers.*

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to gather IP addresses of Remote Nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74597905/6771046)