# Changing `fact_path` in `ansible.cfg` does nothing

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to change the default path of `/etc/ansible/facts.d` for storing Custom Facts to a different directory. As of now, if I store my Custom Facts in this path, I can retrieve them along with the default Ansible Facts in the output of

`ansible myhost -m setup | less`

There is nothing wrong with the Custom Facts and I can see the expected output.

However, if I add the Custom Facts to a different directory, [as explained in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html#parameter-fact_path), called `/home/ansible/facts.d/custom.fact` and define its path in the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` by adding `fact_path=/home/ansible/facts.d/` to it, I can no longer see the Custom Facts in the output of `ansible myhost -m setup | less`.

My `ansible.cfg` now contains the following:

```ini
# (string) This option allows you to globally configure a custom path for 'local_facts' for the implied :ref:`ansible_collections.ansible.builtin.setup_module` task when using fact gathering.
# If not set, it will fallback to the default from the ``ansible.builtin.setup`` module: ``/etc/ansible/facts.d``.
# This does **not** affect  user defined tasks that use the ``ansible.builtin.setup`` module.
# The real action being created by the implicit task is currently    ``ansible.legacy.gather_facts`` module, which then calls the configured fact modules, by default this will be ``ansible.builtin.setup`` for POSIX systems but other platforms might have different defaults.

fact_path='/home/ansible/facts.d/'
```

I have also tried removing the single-quotes, replacing this path with `~/facts.d/` and `$HOME/facts.d/` but nothing worked.

I also tried defining `fact_path=/home/ansible/facts.d/` explicitly in my playbook. However this has not worked out. The playbook now starts in the following way:

```yaml
---
- hosts: kna
  become: yes
  ignore_errors: no
  fact_path: /home/ansible/AnsibleCustomFacts/facts.d/
  gather_facts: yes

# continued playbook
```

How do I change the `fact_path` so that I would be able to get get the combined custom and default facts in the output of `ansible mygroup -m setup | less`?

Comment: It's a INI file and the key value should be `fact_path = /home/ansible/facts.d`

Comment: Yes it is an ini file and I will try adding `fact_path = /home/ansible/facts.d` and let you know if there is an update

Comment: @U880D Hi again - I added replaced this line with the existing one in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` but I am still not able to get any output. To be more precise, I am still seeing: `"ansible_local": {}` in the output of `ansible myhost -m setup | less`

Comment: Just an update - I still have not been able to solve this issue. Please help me out...

Answer (score 1):

With an **`ansible.cfg`** file

```ini
[defaults]

inventory               = ./host
fact_path               = /home/ansible_user/test/facts
# fact_path               = /etc/ansible/facts.d
fact_caching            = yaml
fact_caching_connection = /tmp/ansible/facts_cache
fact_caching_timeout    = 129600
```

an existing and accessible Custom Fact path **`/home/ansible_user/test/facts`** and an Custom Fact file **`test.fact`** with content of

```json
{
  "custom": "ishere"
}
```

a minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - debug:
      var: ansible_local
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  ansible_local:
    test:
      custom: ishere
```

as well an ad-hoc command of

```bash
ansible localhost --module-name setup --args 'fact_path=/home/ansible_user/test/facts filter=ansible_local'
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "test": {
                "custom": "ishere"
            }
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

**Summary**

In an ad-hoc command one will need to specify the module configuration and parameter arguments separately again, otherwise a command

```bash
ansible localhost --module-name setup --args 'filter=ansible_local'
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {
            "default": {
                "custom": "indefault"
            }
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

if there would be the respective Custom Fact file, or just only

```yaml
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_local": {}
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

**Documentation**

- [Introduction to ad hoc commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/command_guide/intro_adhoc.html)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Variable is undefined when running Ansible `debug` ad-hoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74597905/6771046)
- [Ansible AWX Issue #4449 "_ad-hoc commands not using custom `ansible.cfg`"](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/4999)

  > Quote: "*Ad-hoc commands have no project associated with them. Commands are executed against the inventory.*"

Comment: Thank you so much for your response - I will follow your steps for creating a custom-fact file and update you on the same soon.